# Create text files with name of the files from a column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, file, output

I have a data frame in R with the names of the text file (MSU870N.wea, MAU870N.tim, etc) that I want to create in a folder in my computer. How can I do this in R.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to put in those files? do you just want them to be empty text files?

Comment: You have a list of filenames and you need to create those files? Odd, but `for (nm in filenameng$MSU870N) writeLines(character(0), nm)`. With that, you will have your 23 empty files in the current directory.

Comment: This is quick and easy: `file.create(paste("path/to/directory/", filenameng$MSU870N, sep = ""))`

Comment: Yes, I wanted empty files and this worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
fn <- c("test1.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt")

for(name in fn)
  cat("This is a text file's content", file = name)
```